# Access Denied when Creating Folder on Remote Server via IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, networking, permissions

I have a web application deployed on an IIS server with the domain name "XXXXXX082.cs.net" The application, when a user submits a form, attempts to create a folder on another server, "XXXXXX084.cs.net," within the "D" drive's projects folder.

While I can manually create folders on "XXXXXX084.cs.net" from "XXXXXX082.cs.net" without any issues, the web application consistently encounters an "Access Denied" error.

I've verified the following:

1. Permissions: I've checked and ensured that both share and NTFS permissions on the target folder ("\XXXXXX084.cs.net\D$\projects") allow the necessary access.
2. Application Pool Identity: The Application Pool Identity for the IIS application on "XXXXXX082.cs.net" is set to "DefaultAppPool," and I've granted full control access to "DefaultAppPool" for the "projects" folder on "XXXXXX084.cs.net"

Despite these measures, the application continues to report access denied. What might I be missing, and what steps should I take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

My Webconfig:

```
<add key="ProjectFilesRootPath" value="\\XXXXXX084.cs.net\projects\" />
```

my method in controller to create folder.

```
private string ProjectFolderRootPath
        {
            get
            {
                var projectFolderPath=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings().ProjectFilesRootPath;

                return projectFolderPath;
            }
        }


[HttpGet]
        public string createProjectFolder(string id, string PName)
        {
            try
            {
                
                string PId= id;
                string ProName = PName;

                string rootPath = ProjectFolderRootPath.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                string combinedName = $"{PId} {ProName}";

                string projectFolderPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, combinedName);
                projectFolderPath = projectFolderPath.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '/');

                if (!Directory.Exists(projectFolderPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(projectFolderPath);
                }

                return projectFolderPath;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error creating project folder: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

My error:

```
Error creating project folder: Access to the path '//XXXXXX084.cs.net/Projects/10215 Test' is denied.
```

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: First, you need to learn how to describe your IIS configuration, using the standard terms like sites/applications/virtual directories, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Alternatively, locate `applicationHost.config` and show us the the contents in `<sites>` tag.

Comment: You need to assign permission to IIS_IUSRS (full control) to folders, if these steps are not working, then try to give same permission to `NETWORK`, `NETWORK SERVICE` users.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, somewhat confusing when you talk about some "AppPool" identity here.

The user is still going to be IIS_USER.

However, you ALSO don't mention if the 2 computers are on some network with a domain controller or not? (that would mean/suggest that your domain controller server will allow (or not) the permissions here, and thus you would not, could not, and should not set the permissions on the server, since now the domain controller server would be taking care of this issue for you.

However, to save writing 100 pages of suggestions and instructions here?

I suggest you create a new user on the web server (from that server, and NOT a domain user/name. So, create a user with logon + password.

Then on the 84 server, ALSO create the SAME user’s name, with the SAME password.

Now TEST that NEW logon on the '84' server, and make sure it works, and make sure you can create folders in the correct folder with this user. Ok, logout, and now back to server 82, and as noted use this SAME user/logon for the app pool. Keep in mind then that BOTH created users on the 2 servers MUST have the exact same name, and exact same password.

Hence like this:

[image]

The above will/should then simply work.

It not at all clear if the web server is joined to your company network or not (probably NOT a good idea anyway). Regardless even if the 82 server is part of the company domain?
Don't matter, and simply creating a non domain user on EACH of the 2 computers, and then using that logon from the web server app-pool (impersonation) should and will simply work.

As noted, we could go deeper into details here in regards to the domain controller (if being used).
However, as noted, the above approach will and should just work anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the reply:


I appreciate your detailed explanation, and I would like to provide more context to address the concerns raised. When we deploy our .NET application to a Windows server through IIS, we typically enable anonymous authentication for users accessing the website. Additionally, the IIS App Pool under which the web application runs is configured with the necessary permissions to access network resources.

Comment: In our specific setup, we are using two virtual machines within the same network, not two separate physical computers. Users logging into one VM can indeed access the D drive of another VM and create folders because they share the same network.

The challenge arises when attempting to create a folder from the web app, deployed on the IIS server, and accessing the D drive of another server within the same network. Despite the shared network, an "Access Denied" issue occurs.

Comment: OK, but issue is the user for the app pool is not a logged on user and is not a domain user.  So how you going to give permissions to the app pool user that don't exist as domain user and don't exist on 2nd server? Answer: read my above post is how. You didn't necessarily have to create the 2 non domain users, but that's a sure approach. You can also specify (impersonation) a domain logon you create with above instructions. Fact of using vm makes no difference here,  but are vm's part of domain (joined to domain or not) most certainly matters